# Perl: How to generate and validate JWT with rsa algorithm use Crypt::JWT?

Tags: perl, jwt

How to generate and validate JWT with rsa algorithm use `Crypt::JWT`?
I not found any example about how to use [**Crypt::JWT**](https://github.com/DCIT/perl-Crypt-JWT) module, can any one give me a example?

Comment: the github page shows some examples. Start with that and ask a question when you're stuck somewhere. On Stackoverflow it's better to show some code and ask a specific question than to just ask for a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the way to use `Crypt::JWT` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::JWT qw(encode_jwt decode_jwt);
use Crypt::PK::RSA;
use Data::Dumper;

########################
# Encode (Create signature)
########################

my $payload = {
        iss => "issuer",
        sub => "subject",
        exp => time + 86400,
};

my $keyfile = "/path/to/privateKey";
my $key = Crypt::PK::RSA->new($keyfile);
my $alg = "RS256";

my $token = encode_jwt(payload => $payload, key => $key, alg => $alg);
print "token: $token\n";

########################
# Decode (Verify signature)
########################

my $pubkeyfile = "/path/to/publicKey";
my $pubkey = Crypt::PK::RSA->new($pubkeyfile);
my $data = decode_jwt(token => $token, key => $pubkey);
print Dumper \$data;
```

Comment: I just stumbled about this answer and was wandering, should the public key in an public-key-infrastructure should be used for encryption and the private key for decryption. The example above seems to use the private key for encryption and the public key for decryption. That should work in principle, but due to the public key is nothing to be secure, potentially everybody is able to decrypt the message.

Comment: @FrankFörster I have update the comment of the code, `encode_jwt` is used to create signature, not encryption, and `decode_jwt` is used to verify signature, not decryption.

Answer (score 1):

There are examples in the documentation (see, for example, the [MetaCPAN page for the module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::JWT)):

```
# encoding
use Crypt::JWT qw(encode_jwt);
my $jws_token = encode_jwt(payload=>$data, alg=>'HS256', key=>'secret');
my $jwe_token = encode_jwt(payload=>$data, alg=>'PBES2-HS256+A128KW', enc=>'A128GCM', key=>'secret');
 
# decoding
use Crypt::JWT qw(decode_jwt);
my $data1 = decode_jwt(token=>$jws_token, key=>'secret');
my $data2 = decode_jwt(token=>$jwe_token, key=>'secret');
```

What more information do you need?

Comment: I want to use private key sign jwt, and use public key to verify the jwt, how can I do that?