# Perl Crypt::JWT - Unable to capture "invalid signature"

Tags: perl, jwt

Probably pretty simple, but I can not figure out how to catch the failed validation when the wrong key is used to decode a JWT. See below example:

*Example from the answer to: [Perl: How to generate and validate JWT with rsa algorithm use Crypt::JWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65015890/perl-how-to-generate-and-validate-jwt-with-rsa-algorithm-use-cryptjwt) by [Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4857099/ren)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::JWT qw(encode_jwt decode_jwt);
use Crypt::PK::RSA;
use Data::Dumper;

########################
# Encode (Create signature)
########################

my $payload = {
        iss => "issuer",
        sub => "subject",
        exp => time + 86400,
};

my $keyfile = "/root/ssl/jwtRS256.key";
my $keyfile2 = "/root/ssl/jwtRS256-2.key";
my $key = Crypt::PK::RSA->new($keyfile2);
my $alg = "RS256";

my $token = encode_jwt(payload => $payload, key => $key, alg => $alg);
print "token: $token\n\n\n";

########################
# Decode (Verify signature)
########################

my $pubkeyfile = "/root/ssl/jwtRS256.key.pub";
my $pubkeyfile2 = "/root/ssl/jwtRS256-2.key.pub";
my $pubkey = Crypt::PK::RSA->new($pubkeyfile);

my $data = decode_jwt(token => $token, key => $pubkey);

if ( !$data ) {
        print "Error\n\n";
} else {
        print "OK\n\n";
}

print Dumper \$data;
```

I've generated two sets of keys for testing, jwtRS256 and jwtRS256-2. Obviously when the message is encoded and decoded by the matching pair, it works OK. But, when there is a mismatch, and the message does not validate, I can not figure out how to, in code, capture the failure. Instead what happens is the program exits and returns `JWS: invalid signature at ./new-jwt-test.pl line 35` to STDOUT.

I have tried or die(), or warn(), try {} catch {}, nothing seems to catch the failure so I can process it.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution using an eval block to catch the exception:

```
my $data;
eval {
    $data = decode_jwt(token => $token, key => $pubkey);
};
if ($@) {
    print "Error: $@\n\n";
} else {
    print "OK\n\n";
    print Dumper \$data;
}
```

Define $data, eval the decode_jwt, catch any exceptions in $@. Tests OK..

Comment: Or just `my $data = eval { decode_jwt( ... ) }; if ( defined( $data ) ) { ... } else { ... }`, assuming `decode_jwt` can't otherwise return `undef`.